# Semantic segmentation with amazon AWS and S3 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, semantic-segmentation

This is probably a easy question but I have been stuck now for a time.
I want to train an FCN an Amazon AWS. For this I want to use the procedure used in this example ( https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/semantic_segmentation_pascalvoc/semantic_segmentation_pascalvoc.ipynb ) with my own datase.

In contrast to that procedure I have my train and annotation images (as .png) saved in one S3 bucket with four folders (Training, TrainingAnnotation, Validation, ValidationAnnotaion).The files in the folder for Training and Annotation have the same name.

I trained my model with followong code:

```
%%time
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = get_execution_role()
print(role)

bucket = sess.default_bucket()  
prefix = 'semantic-segmentation'
print(bucket)

from sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator import get_image_uri
training_image = get_image_uri(sess.boto_region_name, 'semantic-segmentation', repo_version="latest")
print (training_image)

s3_output_location = 's3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix)
print(s3_output_location)

# Create the sagemaker estimator object.
ss_model = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(training_image,
                                         role, 
                                         train_instance_count = 1, 
                                         train_instance_type = 'ml.p2.xlarge',
                                         train_volume_size = 50,
                                         train_max_run = 360000,
                                         output_path = s3_output_location,
                                         base_job_name = 'ss-notebook-demo',
                                         sagemaker_session = sess)
num_training_samples=5400
# Setup hyperparameters 
ss_model.set_hyperparameters(backbone='resnet-50', 
                             algorithm='fcn',                   
                             use_pretrained_model='True', 
                             crop_size=248, .                             
                             num_classes=4, 
                             epochs=10, 
                             learning_rate=0.0001,                             
                             optimizer='rmsprop', 'adam', 'rmsprop', 'nag', 'adagrad'.
                             lr_scheduler='poly', 'cosine' and 'step'.                           
                             mini_batch_size=16, 
                             validation_mini_batch_size=16,
                             early_stopping=True, 
                             early_stopping_patience=2, 
                             early_stopping_min_epochs=10,    
                             num_training_samples=num_training_samples) 
# Create full bucket names

bucket1 = 'imagelabel1' 
train_channel = 'Training'
validation_channel = 'Validation'
train_annotation_channel = 'TrainingAnnotation'
validation_annotation_channel =  'ValidataionAnnotation'


s3_train_data = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket1, train_channel)
s3_validation_data = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket1, validation_channel)
s3_train_annotation = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket1, train_annotation_channel)
s3_validation_annotation  = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket1, validation_annotation_channel)



distribution = 'FullyReplicated'
# Create sagemaker s3_input objects
train_data = sagemaker.session.s3_input(s3_train_data, distribution=distribution, 
                                        content_type='image/png', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')
validation_data = sagemaker.session.s3_input(s3_validation_data, distribution=distribution, 
                                        content_type='image/png', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')
train_annotation = sagemaker.session.s3_input(s3_train_annotation, distribution=distribution, 
                                        content_type='image/png', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')
validation_annotation = sagemaker.session.s3_input(s3_validation_annotation, distribution=distribution, 
                                        content_type='image/png', s3_data_type='S3Prefix')

data_channels = {'train': train_data, 
                 'validation': validation_data,
                 'train_annotation': train_annotation, 
                 'validation_annotation':validation_annotation}
s3://imagelabel1/Training
ss_model.fit(inputs=data_channels, logs=True)
```

The Errror Message is:

ValueError: Error for Training job ss-notebook-demo-2019-07-15-06-42-25-784: Failed Reason: ClientError: train channel is empty.

Does someone know what is wrong in this Code?

Thank you

Simon

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your folder hierarchy doesn't use the correct names. According to the doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/semantic-segmentation.html#semantic-segmentation-inputoutput), it should look like:

```
s3://bucket_name
    |
    |- train
                 |
                 | - 0000.jpg
                 | - coffee.jpg
    |- validation
                 |
                 | - 00a0.jpg
                 | - bananna.jpg              
    |- train_annotation
                 |
                 | - 0000.png
                 | - coffee.png
    |- validation_annotation
                 |
                 | - 00a0.png   
                 | - bananna.png 
    |- label_map
                 | - train_label_map.json  
                 | - validation_label_map.json
```

Fixing these prefixes should solve your problem:

```
train_channel = 'Training'
validation_channel = 'Validation'
train_annotation_channel = 'TrainingAnnotation'
validation_annotation_channel =  'ValidataionAnnotation'
```